# Oracle order listing by three attributes, but the third attribute of result table do not show in order

Tags: oracle

It is an easy practice, but I am a little puzzled.
My question is why the some THICKNESS do not show in the ascending order.

[image: the practice]

My command:

```
select MATERIALID, MATERIALNAME, MATERIAL, MATERIALSTANDARDPRICE, THICKNESS
from RAWMATERIAL_T
where MATERIAL in ('Cherry','Pine','Walnut')
order by MATERIAL, MATERIALSTANDARDPRICE, THICKNESS;
```

[image: part of the result table]

Comment: PLease post a [mcve] - example table definitions and sample data, expected output.  THanks

Comment: The query is 100% correct. So the answer must have something to do with your setup... so it's not possible to answer without knowing a lot more about it. For example: I could generate such odd results if the price had decimals, but in SQL\*Plus (or whatever I or you use to interact with the database) I used the command `COLUMN MATERIALSTANDARDPRICE FORMAT 999` - then the price would be rounded, so it would look as if THICKNESS needed to be the tiebreaker, when there was no tie to break.

Comment: THICKNESS is a character string, isn't it?

Comment: oh yes! The data type of thickness is varchar

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much.I found that the datatype is varchar.

[DataType](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVPo5.jpg)

Comment: And this means you understand why it sorts as it does?

Comment: Yes, thank you so much. I think because the type is varchar, Oracle just compare the first digit.

Comment: No, Oracle compares them as strings of characters, not as numeric digits.

Comment: Oracle compares as much of the strings as it needs to in order to determine which is "greater" and which is "less", but as shown in your example data "6" sorts *after* "12" because the first character of "6" is greater than the first character of "12". If you had two strings of "61" and "12" they would sort as you expect. One way to work around this is to convert the string to a number when sorting the data. For example, you could change your ORDER BY to `ORDER BY MATERIAL, MATERIALSTANDARDPRICE, TO_NUMBER(THICKNESS)`. Best of luck.